# Insert bootstrap css files for certain angular6 pages

Tags: angular, routes, angular6

I am using angular 6 and right now I am having bootstrap css by putting the css link in my `index.html`.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>cma</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

That puts the bootstrap css in every page.

I want to have the bootstrap css only in my cms routes, like `localhost:4200/cms/anything` .

How can I do this? Putting the css link in every cms html page is not smart. I want to set it once for every cms page. How can I do this? I checked out [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multi-layout-example?file=index.html) but did not get far.

Thanks

EDIT

My routes are

```
const appRoutes : Routes = [
  {path:'', component:HomeComponent},
  {path:'cms/register', component:RegisterComponent},
  {path:'cms/login', component:LoginComponent},
  {path:'cms/profile', component:ProfileComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard] },
  {path:'cms/invitation', component:InvitationComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard] }
];
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have to create a specific route for CMS and then add child routes for whatever components you might want.

```
export const routes: Routes = [
      { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
      { path: 'cms', 
        component: CMSComponent,
        children: [
                      { path: '/anything', component: AnythingComponent }
                  ]}
    ];
```

And then add the bootstrap.css url to **styleUrls** in the CMSComponent. This way the bootstrap will only be available to CMS and it's child components.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-cms',
  templateUrl: './cms.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cms.component.css', './bootstrap.css']
})
export class CMSComponent {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

I haven't tried this yet but maybe something along the lines of this solution might work. Let me know when it does :)

Comment: Nice one, and you respond pretty fast. But the problem here is that there is no `localhost:4200/cms/` page, so what will the `/cms.component.html` have? My cms dont have a `/cms` page. After the login you get redirected to your profile. Check my update in the question, I included my routes. Unless I put the login in the `/cms` route. But then the route for login will be `localhost/cms` that is not representative of the page's functionality.

Comment: This does not work. I downloade a bootstrap css file and I put it in the same folder as the `app.component.ts` Then  I did `styleUrls: ['./app.component.css', './bootstrap.css']` but the content is unstyled.

Comment: If I add `import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';` and `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` it works, but everything is bootstrap styled.

Comment: From the [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#style-scope) "**None** means that Angular does no view encapsulation. **Angular adds the CSS to the global styles**. The scoping rules, isolations, and protections discussed earlier don't apply. This is essentially the same as pasting the component's styles into the HTML."

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the bootstrap file in the component.css file like this:

```
@import "bootstrap/bootstrap"
```

Also you to add change the Encapsulation in the component.ts file to None

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-cms',
  ...,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

This way the bootstrap styles will be applied to the component and to its children.

Note that this works if the bootstrap folder is in the component folder, if it isn't you should link to the proper location of the bootstrap folder (normally in the node_modules folder).

Edit:

Add a component named CmsComponent and in its html file add the below:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Then change your routes to the below:

```
const appRoutes : Routes = [
  {path:'', component:HomeComponent},
    { path: 'cms', component: CmsComponent, children: [
        { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
        { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
        { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent, canActivate:[AuthGuard] },
        { path: 'invitation', component: InvitationComponent, canActivate:[AuthGuard] },
    ]}
]
```

This way the bootstrap css included in the CmsComponent css file will be applied to all the child components.

Comment: I am confused. In what component I add the css? Check my question edit, I included my routes, there is no `localhost/cms` that also has children routes. And frankly, even if I create the `localhost/cms`, what that will include? The login functionality? I guess I could do that, but the url wont be representative of the functionality. A `localhost/cms/login` url would be better...

Comment: Oh I see, you can create a CmsComponent ,add a router outlet in its html file, make a small change in your routes and it will work perfectly, it'll edit my answer to clarify it.

Comment: For this to work I have to install bootstrap to angular? Cant I just include it in the html with links?

Comment: You can download bootstrap to the CmsComponent folder and include it in the Component css file as mentioned above

Comment: @slevin - I wouldn't recommend this approach. From the  [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#style-scope) "**None** means that Angular does no view encapsulation. Angular adds the **CSS to the global styles.** The scoping rules, isolations, and protections discussed earlier don't apply. This is essentially the same as pasting the component's styles into the HTML."

Comment: @AliRida Routes work good but the css has an issue. `import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';` and `  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in my `component.ts`, `@import "bootstrap";` in my `component.css` and a simple `bootstrap.css`. And I get `Module build failed: Error: Can't resolve 'bootstrap' in 'C:\cma\angular-src\src\app\components\cms-component'`

Comment: You have to put the full bootstrap folder in the component folder, this solution works but it isn't the perfect one. @ShauryaDhadwal is right